# Laravel add Auth session variables

Tags: php, laravel-5

After user logging to the system(*Auth::attempt success*)

How to add additional data to the Auth session for user ?

I have user all data but there is no profile image data of user.Profile image of user is save into another table like `user_profile_image`.

I have to set profile image data in `Auth::user()->file_name` till when user logout.

I tried this way:

```
Auth::user()->setAttribute('key','value');
```

and

```
Auth::user()->file_name=$filename;
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just save the user picture:

1. add a migration that adds the `picture` column in the `users` table
2. Use the field to save the picture

   $u = User::find($userId);
   $u->picture = $pathToPicture;
   $u->save();

   then access it with

   $u->picture;
   or 
   Auth::user()->picture;

if you want to add fields to registration form: http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/09/25/adding-custom-fields-to-a-laravel-5-registration-form/

Comment: But according to my project structure for profile image table is different. So I want to add from there.

Comment: so you have the profile image in another table? just add a relation to it in your user model something like
`public function profile(){ return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id'); }`

Comment: yes, in this way i save data all profile image data in auth::user->profile_image . The data in this variable in json. how can i access directly without parsing like we access user_id from auth.

Comment: please post your database tables data (screenshot might help) also your models so we can help you, for example something like http://prntscr.com/bt7r5y